# missing dependencies in package.json when using "create-react-app my-app"

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I tried using both npm and npx but getting same error..missing package dependencies

[image]

Comment: Please try to post any error messages as plain text. Can you also share the generated package.json file that is supposedly missing dependencies?

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
this was the content found in Package.json file

Comment: Yeah, there's no dependencies key there. Do you happen to know what version of create-react-app you have installed? Maybe reinstall it (`npm un -g create-react-app` then `npm i -g create-react-app`).

Comment: create-react-app version 3.4.1, uninstalled create-react-app and reinstalled it.Still same error "Missing Dependencies" while using `npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm`

Comment: @SivakumarSelvaraj I suggest to don't use ```--use-npm``` option. You can install ```create-react-app``` with npm also.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice I also used this command to create app `npm init react-app my-app` still same error..... missing dependencies

Comment: @SivakumarSelvaraj can you share with us your package.json file. This error is very strange.  try to use something like ```npm create-react-app --scripts-version=x.x.x``` and specify the version of the react scripts you would use.

Comment: shared package.json content in my first comment..no dependencies getting added, tried every possible ways to install but is result same error....maybe problem is with my Windows 10. because I installed the same way in my friend's system and it works

Comment: CRA has node and npm dependencies, have you verified you have recent enough versions of each installed on your windows box?

Comment: Yes I checked my `node -v 12.16.3` and `npm -v 6.14.4`....I think this version is enough for CRA....I also tried reinstalling entire node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @DrewReese and @Sorcerer for your replies .......I found that some **.ps1** and **.cmd** files generated to the root folder while using `npx create-react-app my-app`. In order to remove  **.ps1** & **.cmd** files from the root folder i need to remove `prefix` from the file `%USERPROFILE%.npmrc` and it fixed my issue